# SQL - Counting how many associated records another table has

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

As I'm SQL beginner, I can't describe a problem in a simple way, so let me show you an example:

3 Tables:

PRODUCT

- id
- group_id
- person_id

GROUP

- id
- name

PERSON

- id
- group_id

As you see, GROUP can have multiple PERSONs and PRODUCT can be connected with GROUP and PERSON.

From this point, I would like to count number of PERSONs having a PRODUCT within a GROUP

I don't really understand the background of IN or using another SELECT within FROM, so if that's the point, then I'm happy that I was one step before it lol.

```
SELECT 
group.name as GROUP_name, 
COUNT(DISTINCT person_id) AS PERSON_having_min_one_PRODUCT 
FROM products
LEFT JOIN groups ON groups.id = products.group_id 
LEFT JOIN persons ON persons.id = products.person_id;
```

With this data:

```
GROUP
ExampleGroupName1 has 3 PERSONs, but 2 of them has >0 PRODUCTS
ExampleGroupName2 has 3 PERSONs and all of them has >0 PRODUCTS
ExampleGroupName3 has 2 PERSONs, but none of them has the PRODUCT
ExampleGroupName4 has 2 PERSONs, but only 1 has >0 PRODUCT
```

I would like to have an output like this:

```
GROUP_name | PERSON_having_min_one_PRODUCT
ExampleGroupName1 | 2
ExampleGroupName2 | 3
ExampleGroupName4 | 1
```

Comment: This database model has redundancy. If well managed, it should be OK, but most likely you'll be allowing inconsistent values. In short, `PRODUCT` should not have the column `group_id`.

Comment: "As I'm SQL beginner"  One off topic hint: try not using database/table/column names which are (My)SQL [keywords and or reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-L)

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to count number of PERSONs having a PRODUCT within a GROUP

**Note**: I will assume the table `product` does not have the column `group_id`, since it is redundant and can lead to a lot of errors.

The following query will show you the result you want by joining the tables `person` and `product`:

```
select
  count(distinct x.id)
from person x
join product p on p.person_id = x.id
where x.group_id = 123 -- choosing a specific group
  and p.id = 456 -- choosing a specific product
```

Answer (score 0):

This would rather be simple like below meaning all the groups with some `group_id` with `count(persons)` and those count who has some product via id used in having clause

```
         Select group_id,
         count( distinct id ) AS "PERSON_WITH_PRODUCT" 
         from 
         person group by group_id having id
         in (Select id from product);
```